# Remove top and bottom padding of a paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the top and bottom padding of a paragraph text without changing the line height of the text. Please see the image below, I want the top and bottom border without any padding between it and text.
The paragraph height is not fixed.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p{
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 2.2;
    border: 1px solid red;   
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Dqmu8/

Comment: That space is a direct result of the `line-height`, incidentally the `margin` space would appear *outside* of the `border`, it's the `padding` that appears *inside* the border.

Comment: You don't have a `<p>` anywhere in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap in div then give it a negative margin DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/Dqmu8/7/

```
p{
    line-height: 2.2;
    margin:-10px 0 -10px 0;
}
div{
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red; 
}
```

Comment: Can you prove that? Because so far as I can tell ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YRMTX/1/)) it doesn't. Incidentally, his `ul` *already* specifies `padding: 0` which is inherited (admittedly he also didn't have a `p` in his Fiddle).

Comment: he doesn't have any padding, this does nothing to solve the issue. not only that, you have two lines of code to do the same thing? bad code! try `padding:0` next time...

Comment: I was answering you question on this page. The fiddle is a different question and does not contain <p> or padding.

Comment: Your fiddle is due to line-height. That's exactly what line-height is, it's a manual way to set the height of a line of text for the purposes of wrapping text and such. The actual visible size is determined by the font-size and to a lesser extend by the font-family. The average line-height for normal text/font is around 1.2em. Anything larger than that will cause visible letterboxing, which is exactly what you are describing.The only way to fix your exact example is introduce more markup to determine line numbers so that you can style the first/last line differently.

Comment: Vector, sorry I had posted the wrong URL, but anyway it doesnt matter if it was the <p> or <li>, the question was about removing the space from the top and bottom line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its great. I just wanted to say that you cannot use negative padding.

Answer (score 2):

You *can't* achieve this without addressing the `line-height` property (it's the `line-height` that's *causing* the space, after all); however you can specifically target the `line-height` of *only* the `::first-line` pseudo-element:

```
p{
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 2.2;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 0;
}

p::first-line {
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Dqmu8/2/).

Unfortunately there is no `::last-line` pseudo-selector, so it's only possible to target the first.

References:

- [`::first-line` pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#first-line).

Comment: Another caveat is that ::first-line doesn't work with IE8 or anything before it.

Comment: MDN disagrees with quirksmode. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/::first-line

Comment: Thanks David for your answer. Would it be possible to achieve that with by adding additional markup?

Comment: @j08691: that's interesting! This is the first time I'm aware of PPK/Quirksmode being wrong about compatibility (if it *is* wrong, I don't have any IE with which to test, unfortunately).

Comment: @user966582: yes, but *reliably*? You'd need JavaScript, I think, to determine what text is in which line (unless you specifically wrap each line of text into `span` or `div` elements, and use `display: block` or something?).

Comment: Thanks again David, I think the answer by Vector solves the problem.

Comment: @DavidThomas and OP: p:first-line {line-height:1em} doesn't seem to be applied to IE8 AND Fx20. PPK is only testing for a color being applied with this pseudo selector, not the whole (minimal) range of properties written in CSS2.1 `The following CSS properties apply to a ::first-line pseudo-element: font properties, color property, background properties, ‘word-spacing’, ‘letter-spacing’, ‘text-decoration’, ‘vertical-align’, ‘text-transform’, ‘line-height’. UAs may apply other properties as well. `